# Async / await invocations

Tags: javascript, async-await

Hey I'd like to ask you if there is any difference between those two code snippets.

```
//version 1
  public async xxx(
    item: Item
  ): Promise<any> {
    const response = await function();
    return this.merge(response);
  }
//version 2
  public async xxx(
    item: Item
  ): Promise<any> {
    const response = await function();
    return await this.merge(response);
  }

//Calling code: 
const result = await this.xxx(item);
```

So in both cases I am calling xxx method with await statement, but in first example I have return with await and in the second without. What's the difference? Do they both return Promise anyways?

Comment: In this situation, they're identical

Comment: `return await promise;` is as pointless as `return promise.then(value => value);`. it's an additional operation, creating an additional Promise with the same value as the one before.